# How does react identify a component uniquely?

Tags: reactjs

I learned that react uses key to recognise an element (component).

Which of the followings does react consider to recognize an element?
Are there anything else?

- key
- element type
- where the element is located in the entire tree

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in everything you have stated.  You can verify it by inspecting your react application's elements and looking at the components.  For example, you'll see divs with data-reactroot, data-reactid

You may also want to check out https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

Comment: The `data-reactid` attributes are actually gone since React v15.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in that React uses keys to identify instances (components). And while it's not really about performance, keys are used to determine which instances can be reused (and therefore also leads to better performance). If the keys were to change all the time, React would unnecessarily have to recreate nodes, and child components would lose their state.

Every level of your React application has a key. When using JSX, you can specify the key explicitly using: `<Button key={id} />`. If no key attribute is provided, React will use the index of the component (in the current level) to implicitly add a key property to the component.

So why wouldn't you always let React do this for you? For components that maintain data in `this.state`, things can get weird if siblings (in the same level) are removed or re-ordered. You can [read more about this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#child-reconciliation) in the React documentation.